# Component Manager - 500 Internal Server Error - Error in syncing packages for Install

Tags: magento-2.1, component-manager, http-error-500

I freshly installed a magento 2.1.7.

With PHP 7.0.19
Installing the first extension via the compenent manager did work ....
But now i get a 500 Internal Server Error with the message:

Error in syncing packages for Install

Here is the complete error:

```
An error occurred during execution; please try again later.
Additional information:
RuntimeException

File:

    setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/PackagesData.php:88

Message:

    Error in syncing packages for Install

Stack trace:

    #0 setup/src/Magento/Setup/Controller/ComponentGrid.php(98): Magento\Setup\Model\PackagesData->syncPackagesData()
    #1 vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractActionController.php(82): Magento\Setup\Controller\ComponentGrid->componentsAction()
    #2 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
    #3 vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(444): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
    #4 vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(205): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
    #5 vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractController.php(118): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
    #6 vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/DispatchListener.php(93): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
    #7 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
    #8 vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(444): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
    #9 vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(205): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
    #10 vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(314): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
    #11 setup/index.php(31): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
    #12 {main}
```

I tried new keys in magento marketplace, clearing cache, clearing var/di, var/generation, recompling .... but all with no luck.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by making an new account to the magento marketplace.